# how to generate speific periods during serval days in R

Tags: r, time-series

I want to generate the same period during serval days, e.g. from 09:30:00 to 16:00:00 every day, and I know that

```
dates<- seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 9:00",tz='UTC'), as.POSIXct("2000-04-9 16:00",tz='UTC'), by=300)
```

can help me obtain the time series observed every 5 minutes during 24 hours in 100 days. But what I want is the 09:30:00 to 16:00:00 over 100 days.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. We can create a date sequence for every day, and then create sub-list with each day for the five minute interval. Finally, we can combine this list. `final_seq` is the final output.

```
date_seq <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-04-09"), by = 1)

hour_seq <- lapply(date_seq, function(x){
  temp_date <- as.character(x)
  temp_seq <- seq(as.POSIXct(paste(temp_date, "09:30"), tz = "UTC"),
                  as.POSIXct(paste(temp_date, "16:00"), tz = "UTC"),
                  by = 300)
})

final_seq <- do.call("c", hour_seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `tidyr::crossing()` (which I love) and the `lubridate` package:

```r
crossing(c1 = paste(dmy("01/01/2000") + seq(1:100), "09:30"),
         c2 = seq(0, 390, 5)) %>%
  mutate(time_series = ymd_hm(c1) + minutes(c2)) %>%
  pull(time_series)
```